# How to post nested JSON using RestSharp, Xamarin Android

Tags: android, post, xamarin, restsharp

I want to send a raw nested JSON using RestSharp. I am able to send a normal JSON using RestSharp as follows.

```
request.AddBody(new { 
            sender = "Alice", 
            receiver = "Bob", 
            message = "We did it!"});
```

But what I really want to achieve is :

```
request.AddBody(new { 
                bizcardData = "{
                    "name" = "johannes",
                    "company" = "AppLab",
                    "designation" = "Mobile App Developer",
                    "phone" = "5135921240",
                    "email" = "johannes@applab.com",
                }", 
                transData = {
                    "date" = "20150805_221024",
                    "location" = "39.1395996,-84.5295417",
                    "tag" = "sender"
                } 
            });
```

But this code is not working.

I am using Firebase and there is a problem in using POST with AddParameter();
So, I want to send using raw JSO format. I am unable to send a nested JSON this way. It would be great if you could help me with suggestions as of how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: please define "not working" - does it crash?  Throw an exception?  Give you a compiler error?

Comment: The compiler gives an error marking almost every single line in the code I pasted above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're malforming the content mixing strings unterminated instead of nested classes, it will not compile, change it to be real classes:

```
request.AddBody(new { 
            bizcardData = new {
                name = "johannes",
                company = "AppLab",
                designation = "Mobile App Developer",
                phone = "5135921240",
                email = "johannes@applab.com",
            }, 
            transData = new {
                date = "20150805_221024",
                location = "39.1395996,-84.5295417",
                tag = "sender"
            } 
        });
```

This will translate to a JSON object like this:

```
{
    bizCardData: { "name": "johannes", "company": /* and so on */ },
    transData: { "date": "20..:" /* and so on */ }
}
```